# How Can i get last insert element by column (not "_id" column)

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a database containing two fields generate automatic ID and DateLastMaj and I want to retrieve the last element obtained by specifying the DateLastMaj column and not _id

```
    DBCursor d = null;

    DB database= m.getDatabase("LastData");
    DBCollection c = database.getCollection("AirQualityMAJDate");
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("DateLastMAJ", 1);
```

Comment: Did you try sorting by `DateLastMAJ` in descending order and just returning the first element?

Comment: @Thomas DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("DateLastMAJ",0);
Object o = c.find().sort(query).limit(1);